# Page update forgetting dropdown choices after ajac update (php and js) on Magento

Tags: jquery, magento

we have the following code generating a tick box (select payment method). When one chooses the firs method (Ideal/bank) a dropdown list is shown with banks

Now when a user selects a bank & after this the page is refreshed by F5 or ajax requests the same html code is generated but the bank I selected from the list is forgotten

Now, how would I monitor the dropdown and when changed save the value/selection (maybe even only in memory for ajax requests only where the whole page doesnt reload) and when the new ajax request returns and prints the output (without the selectioN) set the selection back?

We use Magento 1.7, and jquery

Hope someone knows a nifty trick

```
<ul class="form-list" id="payment_form_<?php echo $_code ?>" style="display:none">
        <li>
            <label for="<?php echo $_code ?>_bank"><?php echo $this->__(Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/sisow/issuerchoice')) ?> <span class="required">*</span></label><br/>
            <select id="<?php echo $_code ?>_bank" name="payment[<?php echo $_code ?>_bank]" class="input-text validate-text required-entry">
                <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Selecteer een bank...'); ?></option>
                <?php foreach($banks as $bank)
                {
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $bank['value'];?>"><?php echo $bank['label']; ?></option>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <?php echo $this->__(Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/sisow/payoff')) ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The following HTML is generated via AJAX

Now how could we save the option selected under `<select id="sisow_bank"` (probably via onchange) , but then trigger an unload event when the block is reloaded via ajax.

```
<dl class="sp-methods">
    <dt>
            <input id="p_method_sisow" value="sisow" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="Betalen met iDEAL (NL)" onclick="payment.switchMethod('sisow')" checked="checked" class="radio" autocomplete="off">
            <label for="p_method_sisow">Betalen met iDEAL (NL) </label>
    </dt>
        <dd>

    <ul class="form-list" id="payment_form_sisow" style="">
        <li>
            <label for="sisow_bank">Kies uw bank <span class="required">*</span></label><br>
            <select id="sisow_bank" name="payment[sisow_bank]" class="input-text validate-text required-entry" autocomplete="off">
                <option value="">Selecteer een bank...</option>
                                    <option value="01">ABN Amro Bank</option>
                                    <option value="02">ASN Bank</option>
                                    <option value="04">Friesland Bank</option>
                                    <option value="05">ING</option>
                                    <option value="06">Rabobank</option>
                                    <option value="07">SNS Bank</option>
                                    <option value="08">RegioBank</option>
                                    <option value="09">Triodos Bank</option>
                                    <option value="10">Van Lanschot Bankiers</option>
                                    <option value="11">Knab</option>
                            </select>
```

We tried

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var item = window.localStorage.getItem('payment_select');
    jQuery('select[name=payment[sisow_bank]]').val(item);

    jQuery('select[name=payment[sisow_bank]]').change(function() {
       window.localStorage.setItem('payment_select', $(this).val());
    });


});
```

but it doesnt look like the ready function is called after an ajax reload of a div section

Answer (score 0):

Create a new function with the guts of your jQuery ready function.  Call that new function from the jQuery.ready function (which would now be empty except a function call to the new function that you are now adding).  At the end of your ajax call add a call to the new function.